# How to create parameters in this code

Tags: java

I am a first year c.s student, but I am having trouble making this program fit my teacher's requirement. The program will receive a string and an integer that will create this:

```
Please enter a string: ThisIsAnExample

Please enter an integer: 3

Thi
sIs
AnE
xam
ple
```

He wants the for loop to be inside a method called `splitter`. The `splitter` method should have two parameters, a string and an int, for `inputStr` and `inputInt`.

Here is what I have so far:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please enter a string:  "); 
    String inputStr;
    inputStr = keyboard.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Please enter an integer:  ");
    int inputInt;
    inputInt=keyboard.nextInt();
    for(int i =0;i<inputStr.length();i+=inputInt){     
        if(i+inputInt < inputStr.length())
            System.out.println(inputStr.substring(i,i+inputInt));
        else
            System.out.println(inputStr.substring(i,inputStr.length()));
    }
}
```

Comment: So what is your problem? We can understand the desired output But what is the actual output of your code?.

Comment: Where's your splitter method?

Comment: First step would probably to search online for a tutorial on writing methods in Java and then how to call said method. If you are a first year student you probably even have this information in your book.

Comment: My teacher wants me to create a splitter method that will have two parameters, a string and an int, for inputStr and inputInt.

Comment: Your code is working fine. Now create a method.

Comment: Thanks everybody, I'm learning a lot from all of your help

Answer (score 0):

If the splitter method is to actually just print the stuff to standard output, start with:

```
static void splitter (String inputStr, int inputInt) {
}
```

and call it with:

```
splitter (inputStr, inputInt);
```

once you have those values in your main method.

Then it's a simple matter of moving some of your code from `main()` into `splitter()`.

---

If you wanted to return the string array and print it from `main()`, you could use:

```
static String[] splitter (String inputStr, int inputInt) {
}
```

and call it with:

```
String[] bits = splitter (inputStr, inputInt);
// print the array here.
```

This would be a more flexible case if you ever wanted to do something *other* than just print it. For an assignment at this level though, it's probably okay to just print within the method itself.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a function, apparently.

To use a method/function, a few things need to be done:

You need to write the body of your function :

```
public void splitter(String myStringArg,int myIntArg){
// Your code ....///}
```

Finally, you need to call your function. In your main :

```
splitter(myString,myInt);
```

In the splitter body, you'll be able to use `myStringArg`; you will supply its value by calling.
So, in splitter :
`myStringArg = myString` (in value).
Good luck!